# what is the alternative solution for paymentWithProductIdentifier?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

Hi i am using in APP purchase in my project . When i run this project everything works fine, except i am getting a warning message saying that "paymentWithProductIdentifier is deprecated", I gone through the similar questions that are asked in stack overflow but i didn't satisfied. I shown you my coding that i used in the project below

```
SKPayment *payment=[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.dmaker.maker1"];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Can anyone tell me
 1)the alternative for this warning. 
2)or tell me whether this project approve in appstore if i use this existing code.

Answer (score 20):

Try using this:

```
SKProduct *selectedProduct = <#from the products response list#>;
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Comment: Can you tell me the sample code for this line "<#from the products response list#>"

Comment: This is nothing but one of the product which user selects to purchase which you get after calling - (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response.

Comment: To answer surendher for sample code. This goes in didReceiveResponse delegate: SKProduct * selectedProduct = nil;
    selectedProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `paymentWithProductIdentifier:` with following codes:

```
// SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:productId];
// [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:productId];
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
self.productsRequest.delegate = self; // your wrapper for IAP or AppDelegate or anything
[self.productsRequest start];
```

while `productsRequest` is a retain property.

And implement a SKProductsRequestDelegate method:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    self.productsRequest = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options:

- suppress this warning with preprocessor definition:

  ```
  #pragma clang diagnostic push
  #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
  SKPayment *payment=[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.dmaker.maker1"];
  #pragma clang diagnostic pop
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  ```
- create `SKMutablePayment` instead of `SKPayment`:

  ```
  SKMutablePayment *payment = [[SKMutablePayment alloc] init];
  payment.productIdentifier = @"com.mycompany.dmaker.maker1";
  payment.quantity = 1;
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  ```
- use `paymentWithProduct:` convenience initializer:

  ```
  SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:<# product that you received in productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: #>];
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code instead, it does have a little extra that you may already have, but just to make sure

```
#define kInAppPurchaseId "(your product ID here)"

- (void)makePurchase{
//call this when you would like to begin the purchase
//like when the user taps the "purchase" button
NSLog(@"User requests to make purchase");

if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
    NSLog(@"User can make payments");

    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kInAppPurchaseId]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

}
else{
    //the user is not allowed to make payments
    NSLog(@"User cannot make payments due to parental controls");
}
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];
if(count > 0){
    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Products Available!");
    [self purchase:validProduct];
}
else if(!validProduct){
    NSLog(@"No products available");
}
}

- (IBAction)purchase:(SKProduct *)product{
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

I use this code in one off my applications, so it should work.

Comment: Your post doesn't suit the question. The problem is, `paymentWithProductIdentifier` is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Everything works fine but there is still the warning message.