# paymentWithProductIdentifier deprecated in app purchase specific

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the alternative solution for paymentWithProductIdentifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848181/what-is-the-alternative-solution-for-paymentwithproductidentifier)

Hello I am trying to set up in app purchases for ios 5 and newly ios 6. I am being told that my "paymentWithProductIdentifier is deprecated" and I was wondering if someone could tell me how to modify my code, I am a little confused.

```
  SKProduct *selectedProduct = <#from the products response list#>;
  SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

I have seen people suggest the following but I am not sure from my code what "the products response list would be". I thought it would be but its not.

```
 [response.products];
```

Here is my code for the method, if anyone can tell me what to change it would be appreciated thanks!

```
 -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response 

   { 

 SKProduct *validProduct = nil;

 int count = [response.products count];

NSLog (@"count for in app purchases is %d", count);

 if (count>0) {

    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"appUpdate1"];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]; // <-- KA CHING!

     NSLog (@"payment proccessed I think");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming that there is only one product, which you set to validProduct.  You should be able to use

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:validProduct]
```

The productIdentifier is a property of the SKProduct, so this method creates the new payment object with the identifier it gets from the SKProduct.