# How do I correctly use paymentWithProduct: since I can no longer use paymentWithProductIdentifier: when dealing with In-App purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to figure out in-app purchase for iOS.  I keep getting stuck because of the method praymentWithProductIdentifer: has been deprecated.  Here is the code I'd like to be using if the method still worked:

```
- (IBAction)pressBuy20CoinsButton: (id) sender
{

SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.mydomain.inappPractice.20Coins"];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

Now everywhere I look, it says the updated method is paymentWithProduct:  It seems very inconvenient to have lost the Identifier part.  I'm assuming the correct (updated) way of writing my method is something like this:

```
- (IBAction)pressBuy20CoinsButton: (id) sender
{

SKProduct *myProduct =  // not sure what to put here
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:myProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

Let's assume I only have 1 in-app purchase.  Can I somehow access that product with it's specific product identifier in my code?  What is the correct way for me to define SKProduct *myProduct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: as posted here: [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848318/454165)

```
SKProduct *selectedProduct = <#from the products response list#>;
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:selectedProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Comment: I've come across this answer.  I see that the answer talked about using the following code in the delegate method:  selectedProduct = nil; selectedProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];   If this is the case, should I make use _selectedProduct (an instance variable) in the delegate method so I can reference it in my pressBuy20coins method?

Comment: Yes, you can store the selected product on an instance variable when the user press the button so you can know which product you are referencing to.